# How to understand Hebrews 13:4?

Tags: greek, hebrews

There are differing translations of Hebrews 13:4. Here are two examples:

> Let marriage be held in honor among all, and let the marriage bed be undefiled, for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterous. (ESV)

> Marriage is honourable in all, and the bed undefiled: but whoremongers and adulterers God will judge. (KJV)

One set of translations appears to present an imperative ... "Let marriage be held in honor" and the other set appears to state a fact ... "Marriage is honorable".  The same appears to hold for the marriage bed.

I assume this is merely manuscript preference but, just in case, is one rendering more accurate than another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no dispute about the text of Heb 13:4.

The problem is how to translate the first phrase which lacks a verb.  Literally, it says:

> honorable the marriage in/by all ...

"the marriage" is nominative, and "all" is dative; and thus we have the following possibilities -

- [Let] the marriage [be regarded] as honorable by all [people]
- The marriage [should be] honored by all [people]
- The marriage [should be] honored in all [respects]
- Marriage [is] honorable in all [its aspects]
- etc, etc.

In all these possibilities, we must supply an implied verb.  All these possibilities are reflected in the variety of Bible versions extant.  Note that "all" could be referring to either people or the various aspects of marriage; however, the former is much more likely.  Therefore, I regard the first translation above (or similar) to be the most likely intent of the verse.

Hence I would translate Heb 13:4 as:

> [Let] Marriage [be regarded] as honorable by all, and the marriage bed
> undefiled; for God will judge the sexually immoral and adulterers.

Such a sense is given by NIV, ESV, BSB, BLB, etc.

Ellicott says this:

(4) **Marriage is honourable in all**.—Rather, *Let marriage be held in honour among all, and let the bed be undefiled; for fornicators and adulterers God will judge*. The precept is directed against impurity (Hebrews 12:16), and also against the false asceticism of men “forbidding to marry” (1 Timothy 4:3). The laxity of morals among Gentiles (Note on Acts 15:20) and the prevalence of divorce amongst Jews (Matthew 5:32) explain the sudden introduction of such warnings: of these sinners the all-seeing God will be the judge. (Comp. 1 Thessalonians 4:6.)

Comment: I’ve always been curious about such a phrase in Heb 13:4.  +1

Comment: Does "and the marriage bed undefiled" lack a verb as well?  If so, it must be "for God will judge" that drives the meaning, making your first option preferable.

Comment: @MikeBorden - "and the marriage bed undefiled" has no verb either in Greek or English.  "Undefiled" is an adjective.

Comment: ESV says, "and let the marriage bed be undefiled".  That's why I asked.

Comment: @Mike - "let ... be" is a verb that was added to make English sense.

Answer (score 2):

> ... τιμιος ο γαμος εν πασιν και η κοιτη αμιαντος πορνους  ... [TR, undisputed, Hebrews 1:4]

> ... honourable the marriage in all and the bed undefiled ... [Literal EGNT]

This is a construction which English does not have and it is oft misunderstood and almost always translators attempt to 'adjust' it to suit English idiom, which cannot be done.

It is an equivalence.

Two things are stated which are equivalent. They are always so and cannot be not so.
'Our God, consuming fire' (both Hebrew, Deuteronomy 4:24, and Greek, Hebrews 12:29) is an example.

And here, the writer to the Hebrews again chooses such an expression.

'Honourable' and 'the marriage' are an equivalence. Past, present, future and intended. All is honourable.

Comment: I am not sure this is grammatically possible - "honorable" is an adjective here and "marriage" is a noun" and thus cannot be equivalent.  If they were equivalent, then all honorable things would be marriage and vice-versa.  All that one can say here is that marriage is described as honorable, ie, marriage is a subset of those items regarded as honorable.

Answer (score 1):

The whole [passage](https://www.biblewebapp.com/reader/) has imperative verbs, beginning from verse 1 μενέτω *let abide*. Verse 4 has no verb but adjectives, and adjectives don't have moods, only verbs have.

When an adjective asserts something about a nominative subject with a “to be” verb present or implied between the subject and adjective, that adjective is called a predicate adjective. In this case we will add the verb, "let be" or "must be" to indicate the imperative mood. The KJV supplies *is* in italics, which too might have an implied "is *ought to be*" in its sense.

This construct without verb is predicative adjective. Verse 4 has one verb, "God *will judge*", so again, no imperative verb. The next verse also is similar with adjective Ἀφιλάργυρος [Let be] *without covetousness*, and then participle ἀρκούμενοι *being satisfied*. The context is clear that imperative verb is implied. Don't just read one word or verse in isolation but see the context, the imperative starts from the start of the passage and is repeated.

I suggest start learning Greek by yourself, easily with [John Dobson's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801017262), which will save you a lot of time from such doubts, and you will learn it within months. Also use the free Duolingo app for getting more familiar with [modern] Greek.

Comment: Learn Greek by myself?!?  What doubts?  I just had a question, which you and others have answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

When we add "all things are lawful" to this context of Heb 13:1-4 we can see that doing 1-4 is acceptable to married people. We are free to take care of our "neighbor as yourself."
We had no single men when the Bible was written. War and work injuries always kept the ratio women heavy. Today we have single men dying of prostate issues. 30000 per year. We need men sharing their wives. The porn industry is offering stimulus that is unhealthy. The church needs to take an active role in giving single men the stimulation needed. It could be as simple as abiding by "greet one another with a Holy kiss." Will you share your wife to greet a single man with a holy kiss?

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.